# Is it possible to send a push notification using gcm, without a server?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the code, the dependencies and the config files for push notification using gcm in my android project.

Now I'm looking for a way to send a notification to any device that runs my app, but I don't have any server. Is there a way to send push notifications from my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.

A [notifier project](https://github.com/ykartal/GCMNotifier)(I wrote sometimes ago) on [GitHub](https://github.com/ykartal/GCMNotifier)
may help you and you can send notifications via eclipse or any IDE for Java

Comment: I have downloaded your project but I don't understand how to import it to eclipse... I have imported projects before but for some reason this one won't show. Instructions?

Comment: Are you familiar with maven?

Comment: Not so much. I have only complied some services with maven in my android projects (build.gradle)

Comment: On project main page, there is some explanation about usage, it may help? You can create a main class and call the method as described

Comment: No it didn't help... Can I talk to you somehow? I need a quick explanation

Comment: Let's talk on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108109/gcm-notification-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTTP request to send a GCM message from any computer as long as you have the authorization key at hand. Google's GCM documentation at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#auth has example cURL requests that you can further enhance to contain the message you'd like to send.

```
# api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

# curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
       -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```